# Checking answer of conditional probability question

Tags: probability

I tried to solve this probability question, but I wanted to check my answers. Thank you.

Problem 3. Consider a set $X$ that contains 80% of all possible 7-digit numbers. (Examples of 7-digit numbers include 1234567 and 0000001.)

1. What is the probability that a 7-digit number chosen uniformly at random is in $X$?

Answer: 80%

2. Suppose the items in set $X$ are unknown to us, but we have a randomized data structure that can be used to test membership in $X$.  We interact with the data structure by issuing queries of the following form: Does the set contain element $x$? The data structure will then respond either Yes or No. Unfortunately, the data structure sometimes gives us a wrong answer: If it is queried on a 7-digit number $x$ that is not contained in set $X$, it tosses 3 independent, fair coins.  If all 3 coins come up heads, it gives the wrong answer.  (That is, it says 'Yes'). In all other cases, it gives the right answer. 
   What  is  the  probability  that  the  data  structure  says  'Yes'  on  a  randomly  chosen  7-digit number $z$?

Answer: I figured this was a conditional probability question.

Let $A$ be the event that the function says yes to a given input.

Let $B$ be the event that element $x$ is in the Set $X$.

Let $C$ be the event that element $x$ is not in the Set $X$.

$$P(A) = P(B) P(A\mid B) + P(C) P(A\mid C) = \frac{8}{10} + \frac{1}{40} = \frac{33}{40} = .825 \enspace.$$

3. Suppose we choose a random 7-digit number $y$, issue the query:  Does the set contain element $y$?", and the data structure responds with 'Yes'. What is the probability that $y$ is contained in set $X$?

Answer: Again, I assumed a conditional probability problem.

Let $Z$ be the event that $y$ is in Set $X$.

Let $A$ be the event that the structure returns yes.

$$ P(Z\mid A) = \frac{P(Z) P(A\mid Z)}{P(A)} = \frac{.8}{.825} = 97\% \enspace. $$

Any feedback or advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't take the coin tosses into account, or that I'm currently not. Because i had factored in the coin probabilities. Can you show me what the probability should look like?

Comment: First, a clarification.  What does $x = 2X$ mean? (Is $X$ still the set of numbers?)

Comment: i apologize, the symbol didn't copy and past correctly. that "2" was supposed to be the symbol to represent that x is not contained in the set X.

Comment: OK.  Then you answer to (2) is correct.

Comment: ...and so it your answer to (3).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

All three answers are correct. My only comment is on question 3, where you say "I assumed a conditional probability problem", but I believe you know that this is Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 0):

While your math is correct, problem 2 isn't really a conditional probability problem.  Note that $C=!B$ and $P(B)P(A|B)=P(A\&B)$. Thus, your formula boils down to $P(A)=P(A\&B)+P(A\&!B)$. While it makes sense to *use* conditional probabilities to calculate $P(A\&B)$ and $P(A\&!B)$, the final answer is not a conditional probability (except to the extent that all probabilities are in some sense conditional).